# Keeping track of multiple bases in Minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

In Minecraft, I often lose track of some of the chests that I've created, as well the bases that I've made, so I keep losing some of the items that I've collected. Is there any efficient way to keep track of multiple bases in Minecraft, besides writing down the coordinates of each base and using the `F3` key to travel to each one?

Comment: Perhaps it would be easy to "link" multiple bases together using Nether Portals, taking advantage of the fact that it's possible to move faster in the Nether than in the overworld. (However, some Minecraft servers specifically disallow nether portals, so I'll need to find other options as well).

Comment: Also, on multiplayer servers, you'd need some way to protect the Nether portals from other players, so that they wouldn't be damaged.

Answer (score 8):

One easy and organizable way would be to use [Rei's minimap mod](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/482147-147-jan10-reis-minimap-v32-06/). It is a really nice mod where you can create waypoints that can be seen on the mini map and in the game. Most servers allow it, but double check if you're not sure.

Another simpler way would be to make pillars out of bright, noticable materials (birch wood, snow, etc.) and putting glowstone/torches at the top so they can be seen easily from a distance. If your bases are far away from each other, you could try making smaller waypoints along the way, to stay on track.

[image]
Note that some servers will ban or kick players who make large, 1x1 towers (thank you SevenSidedDie), so be careful. If you really had the time you could make a fancy 3x3 or 4x4 tower, or you could just make 3-5 high tall pillars, here and there, denoting a path.

Or you could make a trail of some sort on the ground (gravel is nice). The problem with this one is that it would require a good bit of time for something you will use minimally.

Comment: Note that some server ban users who build that sort of tower.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Very true... I was thinking of it from a singleplayer stand point. I'll edit that.

Comment: wood for charcoal & sticks is cheap if you build a tree farm. make a trail of torches. If the distance isn't too great, I use gravel roads/stone brick bridges & hollow out paths through mountains, with signposts for different bases (something like Crazy Lava Waterfall, Zombie Dungeon Arena, Floating Sanctuary etc.) But that's on Singleplayer. I've been on multiplayer servers that barely let you build a house, let alone make roads and stuff.

Comment: Making a canal (using 2x2 infinite water sources, placed adjacently and then connected) would probably be easier than making a gravel or dirt road. It would also allow for fast travel by boat. :)

Comment: @AndersonGreen please mark that this only works on flat route and this usually requires loads of digging. another possibility to keep track and travel fast would be a railroad.

Comment: I think the iron needed to create a couple of buckets would be a lot less than the iron needed to create a railroad. I've often build a railroad to a quarry but found I've used all the material from the quarry building the track to it...

Comment: @tombull89 I also think it would be easier to dig a canal than to build a railroad - you'd have an unlimited supply of water to work with if you created it using 2x2 infinite water sources.

Comment: One question still needs to be addressed: does Rei's Minimap Mod work on vanilla Minecraft servers?

Comment: @AndersonGreen, I believe the Minimap Mod is clientside so it should work okay. I don't use it though.

Comment: Yes, the minimap is client-side and doesn't need to cooperation of the server at all.

Answer (score 1):

Make copies of your map and put one in an item frame in each base. When you walk nearby it will show up on your map if you are carrying one with you. It's a bit glitchy but it works pretty well if you don't want to install a mod just for this. Another easy way is to craft a journal and write the coordinates in it for each of your bases, then toss it in an ender chest so you can grab it from anywhere.

If you're going to use a mod, you may as well use mystcraft or dimensional doors to warp directly between bases and cut the map part out altogether.

Comment: Will either of those mods work on multiplayer servers?

Comment: not unless they are installed on the server.

Comment: If you're running a bukkit server, use multiverse or another server plugin to make warps.

Comment: @AndersonGreen not unless either mod is installed on both, client and server.

Answer (score 1):

If you're playing in single player and willing to "cheat" you might want to use teleporters. Easy to make, fast travel, and safe. This video explains how to make them using command blocks.

Answer (score 0):

One could just use Dimensional Doors as a central mystcraft and storage base hub with ender chests as a storage network interface. If one includes ProjectE and/or backpack mod and one can use project-e's alchemist bags or backpack mod's backpacks as folders with the either one's ender chest item to remotely access your ender storage.

As much as I love mystcraft there I should offer a far warning though, mystcraft does tend to increase lag( and cpu usage) when popping around a lot; mostly because minecraft either orphans chunks and keeps them loaded in memory when they're meant to be unloaded. Most of the latest releases solves this and also waiting around a few minutes before popping into the next link book works too.